# Exception trying to post a link on Facebook page using grahp API for PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've already searched among the other questions here on Stackoverflow and on other websites, but I couldn't find a solution, also because it seems that FB often changes the authentication method, so old solutions are no more valid.
I'm using SDK4 and this is my code as I have it at the moment

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);

$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

try {
    $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

if($session)
{
    try {
        $response = (new FacebookRequest(
            $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
                'link' => 'www.mysite.it',
                'message' => 'some text'
            )
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
        echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
        echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode() . 
             " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I get this message:

> "Exception occured, code: 2500 with message: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Given the message, the session is correctly created and validated, the problem is on the execute() method, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've created your session for your app, but to post on a users behalf you need to get an access token for said user and then call

```
$this->facebook = new FacebookSession($access_token);
```

Comment: I actually need to post as the app itself, not in name of the user who created the content on the website. The post on the FB page should be posted with the name of the page, not with the name of another FB user.  
Do I need to get an access_token anyway?

Comment: Post as the app? Do you mean post to a page?

Comment: Yes, I want to post from my website to a Facebook page which I own using the page's name.

Comment: You need to get the access token for the page by pulling up the user who has admin access to that page.